# convert JSON to c# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-core, converters, system.text.json

I have a .json file which I want to convert to a c# dictionary (string, string).

the JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "data": "data",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "data": "data2",
        "id": "2"
    }
]
```

what is the simplest way to achieve it?

Comment: What you have would be converted to an array of dictionaries. But, that aside, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried             string json = File.ReadAllText(@"PATH"); but it seems to return a weird string

Comment: What dictionary do you want to get?  `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "data","1" }, {"data2", "2"} }`?

Comment: @dbc - I would guess id would be the dictionary‘s key and data the value

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in your question is an array of objects containing two properties corresponding to keys and values, and you would like to map that to a `Dictionary<string, string>` containing those keys and values, e.g. `{"data":"1","data2":"2"}` or `{"1":"data","2":"data2"}` (your question isn't clear which you want).

To do that, first introduce a DTO corresponding to the JSON objects in your array:

```
record DataItemDTO(string data, string id);
```

But in versions of c# earlier than c# 9 / .NET 5, as mentioned by @[flydog57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4739488/) instead define:

```
public class DataItemDTO { public string data {get; set;} public string id {get; set;} }
```

And now you can do:

```
await using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
var list = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<DataItemDTO>>(stream);
var dictionary = list?.ToDictionary(d => d.data, d => d.id);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kI3zRq).

Or, if you want the `"id"` property to be used as the dictionary key, do:

```
var dictionary = list?.ToDictionary(d => d.id, d => d.data);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JZIRYM).

If you would prefer to use synchronous IO, do:

```
using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DataItemDTO>>(stream);
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/On5TE7).

Notes:

- Here `path` is a c# string containing the path to your JSON file on disk.  In your comment you mentioned you tried `File.ReadAllText(@"PATH")` but this code likely failed because it attempted to read a file named `PATH` not a file located at some specified path.
- If your array of JSON objects contains duplicate values for the dictionary key property, e.g. if you want to use `"data"` as the key:

  ```
  [
      {
          "data": "data",
          "id": "1"
      },
      {
          "data": "data",
          "id": "2"
      }
  ]
  ```

  You will get a `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added` constructing the dictionary.

Comment: If you are not running a recent compiler (i.e., one that understands `record`), you can create a simple POCO class: `public class DataItemDto { public string data {get; set;} public string id {get; set;} }`

Comment: @Flydog57 - correct, but most people using System.Text.Json are also using .NET 5 or later.